# loading .so library C++

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I'm trying load library library.so, when i try if exist return true, but when I use dlopen return library doesn't exist.

```
std::ifstream ifile("library.so"); if (ifile) {
    cout << "Exist!" << std::endl; }

cout << "C++ dlopen demo\n\n";

// open the library cout << "Opening hello.so...\n"; void* handle = dlopen("library.so", RTLD_LAZY);

if (!handle) {
    cerr << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
    return 1; }
```

Comment: It might be that the ifstream object locks the file object, try doing a `ifile.close()` before using dlopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dlopen` is quite restricted in the paths it can search (to keep it short: the default paths plus `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable -- see the full [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) for a complete list). Your `ifstream` looks in the current directory (whatever it is), which is quite probably not included by default in the paths that `dlopen` considers.

Solutions include:

- Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly (which is usually the preferred method).
- Using an absolute path instead of a relative one.
- Putting your library in one of the default paths (eg. `/lib` or `/usr/lib`).