# Load lib dynamicly at runtime don't work

Tags: c++, vtk

I try to load a *.so at runtime with the following code:

```
handle = dlopen(Path, RTLD_LAZY);
create = (FunctionEquationInterface* (*)())dlsym(handle, "CreateClass");
destroy = (void (*)(FunctionEquationInterface*))dlsym(handle, "DestroyClass");
```

the `FunctionEquationInterface` looks like:

```
class LocalFunctionImplementation : public FunctionEquationInterface
{
public:
    virtual int CreatePolynom(vtkUnstructuredGrid *input, vtkDataArray *coefficientArray);
    virtual double Evaluate(Point *point);
};

extern "C" LocalFunctionImplementation* CreateClass();
extern "C" void DestroyClass(LocalFunctionImplementation*);
```

I build the lib with cmake

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED LocalFunctionImplementation.cpp)
```

The problem is that the lib will not be loaded. The `handle` is still NULL.

I think it's a problem with the linking of VTK but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What `Path` are you using?

Comment: It's a `char*` variable

Comment: I meant, what is its content? Depending on the exact content of `Path` the system may not be able to find your library. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16335841/2070725 (dunno if this is your actual problem, but at first glance I don't see anything else wrong)

Comment: Its to correct filepath to the .so I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works. I needed `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})`. So the lib will be loaded